# Unable to Build and Run DotNet Core from VS 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, .net-core

#### Issue

I have been unable to build and run any dotnet core application from Visual Studio 2017 (15.5.2). Every time I attempt to run it, VS2017 immediately goes into Break Mode, and stops debugging when I hit continue.

This happens even when I use the New Project from VS2017 and choose a .NET Core template (Console App or ASP.NET Core Web Application).

I have followed Microsoft's directions at [Build a C# Hello World app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio), and have completed the instructions at [Prerequisites for .NET Core on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/windows-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x).

#### What I Have Tried

- Uninstalling and reinstalling the .NET Core cross-platform development workload in VS2017.
- Removing all .NET Core SDK versions from Programs and Features and reinstalling from [.NET Core 2.x SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core)

#### What I Can Do

- Navigate to the source directory and run `dotnet run` in Powershell. This successfully runs the application in the terminal.

  - If I guess the dotnetcore PID correctly, I am able to attach to the running process in VS2017.
- Open the project in Visual Studio Code. After VSCode creates the build configurations, it is able to build and debug the code.

I do a majority of development in VS2017, and would prefer to use it for dotnet core as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
dotnet restore
```

is very likely to be your best friend. If any files are missing they can be easily recovered in this way. For example, when I created a new VS2017 ASP.NET project I kept getting "System could not be found" errors throughout until I executed the restore command, and now I am on my way. Have you tried that?

Comment: I tried `dotnet restore`, but it did not seem to make a difference. I can use `dotnet run` just fine, so I don't think it is a problem with the project or the CLI.